# Implicit conversion loses integer precision after importing firebase package

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am getting 131 warnings of this type `Implicit conversion loses integer precision...` after I imported firebase packages to my Xcode project. The errors are pointing to many `.h` files

[Here](https://github.com/vladponcea/deliveryApp) is the full source code of my project.

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

This problem solved in my project by click *File* -> *Resolve Package Versions*:

[image]